# Upload image to database and display in another page. How to call a php file from one php file to display resukt

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner in PHP. I got a task to create an admin panel and upload an image to database and it should display on another page. Now I tried but the result is coming on the same page.
And some error is also present there.

```
" Deprecated: `mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp64\www\Image Upoad PHP\Img Up [www.students3k.com]\Upload photos\config.php on line 7".`
```

Code:

1. index.html

   ```
   <form action="addexec.php" method="post"      enctype="multipart/form-
    data" name="addroom">
   Select Image: <br />
   <input type="file" name="image" class="ed"><br />
    Caption<br />
   <input name="caption" type="text" class="ed" id="brnu" />
   <br />
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" id="button1"  
   onclick="a.php"/>
   ```

   ```
   <?php
        include('config.php');
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
             echo '<div id="imagelist">';
             echo '<p><img src="'.$row['location'].'"></p>';
             echo '<p id="caption">'.$row['caption'].' </p>';
             echo '</div>';
        }
       ?>
   ```

2.addexce.php

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
echo "";
}else{
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

        $location="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $caption=$_POST['caption'];

        $save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (location, caption) VALUES ('$location','$caption')");
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();                 
}
```

?>

3.config.php

```
<?php
   $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
   $mysql_user = "root";
   $mysql_password = "root";
   $mysql_database = "photoupload";
   $prefix = "";
   $bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or 
   die("Could not connect database");
   mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");
   ?>
```

Comment: r u able to insert data in DB??

Comment: The message which you got clearly states what the problem is and what needs to be done. What exactly is the question there?

Comment: yes, able to add data to db. that image is displaying in index.php itself. but i want to display it in another page

Comment: @Vandanak2012:added ans check it.

Answer (score 0):

in `addexce.php` file

with header `header("location: index.php");` we donot have that feasbility.

so try below

replace `header("location: index.php");`

with  `echo '<script>window.open("here add total url","_blank");</script>';`

Comment: Can you pls help me to add an remove option to delete image from database